# Autoloader appears to be omniscient | Nested includes not needed

Tags: php, autoloader

I use this simple autoloader code:

```
function __autoload( $class_name ) { include 'class.' . $class_name . '.php'; }
```

and I make this call `new SDB();`

`SDB` actually inherits from `SDBOne` which I never include...yet the auto-loader loads it.

This means it knows to load modules nested / included in other modules.

So from the looks of it I never need to require or include anything if I use the auto-loader.

However, if I use a stand alone module where there is no auto-loader, I then need to include the class it inherits from.

Should I use

```
require,

require_once,

include,

include_once.
```

I would guess to go with `require_once` because I want an error not a warning...plus when I use the code with the autoloader I don't want it loaded twice.

Basically I have 2 types of use for SDB : one with the autoloader present and one with out.

**Reference**

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct, `require_once` would be the correct way to include a parent class or dependent class in one file.  That way if its included multiple times, the `require_once` prevents errors that would arise from redeclaring a class.

The autoloader is autoloading `SDBOne` automatically because it needs that class defined before it can extend `SDB` from it.  The same thing is happening to autoload the parent class on demand as happens when you try to load the inherited class.

Also, you should consider switching to [`spl_autoload_register`](http://php.net/spl_autoload_register) so that your code will work well with other code that may use an autoloader.  The SPL autoloader supports multiple autoloaders and creates a stack in the order they are registered.  This way if the first autoloader doesn't satisfy the requirement, it keeps trying subsequently registered autoloaders until the class is loaded or cannot be found.

Another note on preventing errors, you may want to change your autoload function as follows:

```
function __autoload( $class_name ) { 
    $file = 'class.' . $class_name . '.php';
    if (file_exists($file)) {
        include $file;
    }
}
```

Because if the class being autoloaded doesn't exist, you will get errors about including a non-existent file.  This is especially important when using `spl_autoload_register`; you don't want your autoloader to emit unnecessary warnings about missing files if another autoloader will be ultimately responsible for loading the class in question.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Defensive coding...never, Offense is the best defense. :)

Comment: @HiroProtagonist :) yeah I'm always on the offense